# Exception handling in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

So, I wrote a small Tkinter program in python. The program executes good, but its easy for an exception to occur if theres a non-digit character entered into a field.

so, I tried to remedy it, but my remedy fails:

and here is the issue:

```
try:
            self.laborOne = float(self.trimmerOne_Entry.get()) * 8
            self.laborTwo = float(self.trimmerTwo_Entry.get()) * 8
            self.laborThree = float(self.operator_Entry.get()) * 8
            self.addedThem = self.laborOne + self.laborTwo + self.laborThree
            self.laborTotal.set(str(self.addedThem))
            self.perUnitLabor = self.addedThem / 125
            self.laborUnit.set(str(self.perUnitLabor))
except ValueError:
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Error:', 'One or more of your values was not numeric. Please fix them.')
        self.performIt()
            self.performIt()
```

At first I tried just showing the messagebox in the error handling, but that closes the program when you click ok. SO, I tried recursion, calling the function to itself. When this happens, the dialog box just stays there. because self.performIt doesn't need an arg passed in, I passed (self) into it just to try it. THIS allows me to fix my values in the boxes, which is what I am looking for, but causes a different exception

Anyway, how can I handle the ValueError exception without the program terminating, so that a user can enter corrected data?

Complete code

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox

class MyGui:
    def __init__(self):
        #create the main window widget
        self.main_window = tkinter.Tk()

        #create 6 frames: 
        #one for each trimmers/operators pay,
        #one for buttons
        #one for outputs
        self.trimmerOne = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.trimmerTwo = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.operator = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.rotaryLabor = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.rotaryLaborUnit = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.buttonFrame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)

        #create and pack widgets for Trimmer 1
        self.trimmerOne_Label = tkinter.Label(self.trimmerOne, text='Enter the payrate for trimmer 1: ')
        self.trimmerOne_Entry = tkinter.Entry(self.trimmerOne, width=10)
        self.trimmerOne_Label.pack(side='left')
        self.trimmerOne_Entry.pack(side='left')

        #create and pack widgets for Trimmer 2
        self.trimmerTwo_Label = tkinter.Label(self.trimmerTwo, text='Enter the payrate for trimmer 2: ')
        self.trimmerTwo_Entry = tkinter.Entry(self.trimmerTwo, width=10)
        self.trimmerTwo_Label.pack(side='left')
        self.trimmerTwo_Entry.pack(side='left')

        #create and pack widgets for Operator
        self.operator_Label = tkinter.Label(self.operator, text='Enter the payrate for operator: ')
        self.operator_Entry = tkinter.Entry(self.operator, width=10)
        self.operator_Label.pack(side='left')
        self.operator_Entry.pack(side='left')

        #create and pack widgets for rotaryLabor
        self.rotaryLabor_Label = tkinter.Label(self.rotaryLabor, text="This is what it cost's in trimmer labor: ")
        self.laborTotal = tkinter.StringVar() #to update with laborTotal_Label
        self.laborTotal_Label = tkinter.Label(self.rotaryLabor, textvariable=self.laborTotal)
        self.rotaryLabor_Label.pack(side='left')
        self.laborTotal_Label.pack(side='left')

        #create and pack widgets for labor Unit
        self.rotaryLaborUnit_Label = tkinter.Label(self.rotaryLaborUnit, text="This is the cost per part in trim labor: ")
        self.laborUnit = tkinter.StringVar() #to update with laborTotal_Label
        self.laborUnit_Label = tkinter.Label(self.rotaryLaborUnit, textvariable=self.laborUnit)
        self.rotaryLaborUnit_Label.pack(side='left')
        self.laborUnit_Label.pack(side='left')

        #create and pack the button widgets
        self.calcButton = tkinter.Button(self.buttonFrame, text = "Calculate", command=self.performIt)
        self.saveButton = tkinter.Button(self.buttonFrame, text = "Save", command=self.saveIt)
        self.quitButton = tkinter.Button(self.buttonFrame, text = "Quit", command=self.main_window.destroy)
        self.calcButton.pack(side="left")
        self.saveButton.pack(side="left")
        self.quitButton.pack(side="left")

        #pack the frames
        self.trimmerOne.pack()
        self.trimmerTwo.pack()
        self.operator.pack()
        self.rotaryLabor.pack()
        self.rotaryLaborUnit.pack()
        self.buttonFrame.pack()

        tkinter.mainloop()

    #define the function that will do the work:
    def performIt(self):
        try:
            self.laborOne = float(self.trimmerOne_Entry.get()) * 8
            self.laborTwo = float(self.trimmerTwo_Entry.get()) * 8
            self.laborThree = float(self.operator_Entry.get()) * 8
            self.addedThem = self.laborOne + self.laborTwo + self.laborThree
            self.laborTotal.set(str(self.addedThem))
            self.perUnitLabor = self.addedThem / 125
            self.laborUnit.set(str(self.perUnitLabor))
        except ValueError:
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Error:', 'One or more of your values was not numeric. Please fix them.')
        self.performIt()
            self.performIt()

    def saveIt(self):
        self.laborOne = float(self.trimmerOne_Entry.get()) * 8
        self.laborTwo = float(self.trimmerTwo_Entry.get()) * 8
        self.laborThree = float(self.operator_Entry.get()) * 8
        self.addedThem = self.laborOne + self.laborTwo + self.laborThree
        self.laborTotal.set(str(self.addedThem))
        self.perUnitLabor = self.addedThem / 125
        self.laborUnit.set(str(self.perUnitLabor))
        file = open("log.txt", 'w')
        file.write("Trimmer One gets paid: " + str(self.laborOne))
        file.write("\n___________________________________________\n")
        file.write("Trimmer Two gets paid: " + str(self.laborTwo))
        file.write("\n___________________________________________\n")
        file.write("Operator gets paid: " + str(self.laborThree))
        file.write("\n___________________________________________\n")
        file.write("The sum of thier daily labor is: " + str(self.addedThem))
        file.write("\n___________________________________________\n")
        file.write("If production is reached, the labor cost is" + str(self.laborOne) + "per unit")
        file.write("\n___________________________________________\n")
        file.close()



testRun = MyGui()
```

Comment: Is that really you code? something looks a bit off..

Comment: if this is really your code, I'm surprised it even runs because of the ValueError in the except block.

Comment: whole code is on the pastebin

Comment: IT Ninja, I now have it changed to this:  except ValueError:
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Error:', 'One or more of your values was not numeric. Please fix them.')
            self.performIt()

Comment: External sources can't be trusted. You should always post your code here, so that it is good for the future viewers. (external links might not work later on)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the ValueError exception handler, only an error needs to be shown. After `performIt` returns,  the GUI will still be there.

Comment: Thank you. Wierd-- the first time I ran it like this the GUI closed. Now it stays open. Maybe just a fluke the first time. Thanks.

Comment: @user2962806 Maybe you forgot to save the file before running it. Happens to me.

Answer (score 3):

That's not how you catch errors. Do it like this:

```
except ValueError:
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Error:', 'One or more of your values was not numeric. Please fix them.')
```

You don't need to call the function again.

Comment: again, this causes an endless loop. Seems to only break loop if I pass in an un-needed argument in my recursion

Comment: Why would you need to recreate the buttons?